# activity with animation crashing at startup

Tags: android

my project on android studio is crashing at startup, can't seem to find whats wrong with it, its debugging fine but crashing when I open the app.

I see an error from the image view maybe but what causes the error? Thanks in advance.

**log:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.lrtapp.ardentmap, PID: 19679
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lrtapp.ardentmap/com.lrtapp.ardentmap.welcomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class ImageView
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class ImageView
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                      at com.lrtapp.ardentmap.welcomeActivity.onCreate(welcomeActivity.java:20)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696) 
                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.lrtapp.ardentmap:drawable/lrtlogo" (7f07008d)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f07008d a=-1 r=0x7f07008d}
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2441)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
                      at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
                      at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:135)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:71)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:67)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:181)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:105)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                      at com.lrtapp.ardentmap.welcomeActivity.onCreate(welcomeActivity.java:20) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

**Here's my xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".welcomeActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/lrtlogo"/>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="EaseRoute by Lrt Line 2"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/trainformob"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttontomainmenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Main Menu"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonstyle"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.lrtapp.ardentmap">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/erlogo"
        android:label="EaseRoute"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:label">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyALC_Pis5w391INiqcvnXO7dipxuMP0-JA" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>

        <activity android:name=".MapActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".About" />
        <activity android:name=".Contact" />
        <activity android:name=".Videos" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <service
            android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:stopWithTask="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

        <activity android:name=".ContactMenu" />
        <activity android:name=".welcomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

May I ask for help to solve this. Would appreciate every answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess line 16 in your xml refers to the `ImageView` with this attribute:

```
android:src="@drawable/lrtlogo"
```

Possible reasons for the error:

1. The drawable is not in the `Drawable` folder but in a folder like `Drawable-v24` so it can't be found.
2. The drawable is too large and the ImageView can't be inflated.
3. Since you mention animation in the title of your question, if this drawable has anything to do with this animation (I don't know because you did not post yhe code), maybe the drawable itself or the animation it is involved in is invalid or the colors it uses are invalid or can't be found.

**Edit** now the error points to this drawable:

```
android:background="@drawable/trainformob"
```

Comment: Hi, after I re-pasted the png file on the drawable folder(not the v24 anymore), the app still crashes at launch. I'll post the new log error?

Comment: If it is any different yes.

Comment: I just posted a new answer which contains the log, by the way, how do you see the error on the log? I'm sorry im new to this.

Comment: Since the error now is different, this means that the previous error was solved when you pasted the other drawable in `drawable` folder. Now check  `trainformob`.

Comment: Hi, I changed them both, removed the v24 from the both files, now they're not crashing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.lrtapp.ardentmap:drawable/lrtlogo" (7f07008d)  is not a Drawable (color or path):

You are referencing `drawable` that is either incorrect file format or not available for given qualifier (i.e. you have separate `drawable` and `drawable-xxx` folders one one is lacking that file.

Comment: Hi, after I re-pasted the png file on the drawable folder(not the v24 anymore), the app still crashes at launch. I'll post the new log error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file `lrtlogo`  exists on Drawable folder.

Comment: Hi, it's on my drawable folder. the png file of the picture.